# Getting table names of all tables in a particular database in MS SQL Server using Java

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc

I am trying to get the names of all tables in a database in using Java.

This is the method I am using. However, on running it, it also lists other tables, which are not actually part of my database, or maybe some system tables that I am not interested in. How can I get only the tables which I have created?

```
/* connecting to database using supplied credentials, and printing out the SQL queries for inserting data to local db */
    public void connectToAzure(String connectionString, String databaseName, String username, String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  

        final Connection m_Connection = DriverManager.getConnection( connectionString+";DatabaseName="+databaseName, username, password );
        final ArrayList<String> tables = getTableNames(m_Connection);
    }

/* helper method to get table names */
    public ArrayList<String> getTableNames(final Connection m_Connection)
    {
        final ArrayList<String> tables = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            DatabaseMetaData dbmd = m_Connection.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                String tableName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                tables.add( tableName );
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return tables;
    }
```

Output on running the above

```
table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, trace_xe_action_map, trace_xe_event_map
```

Of these,

```
trace_xe_action_map, trace_xe_event_map
```

are not tables that I have created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to run a simple select query on the database like this:

```
select TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

You can further filter out the table_names using where clauses like these:

```
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE
    TABLE_CATALOG = ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?;
```

Comment: That is what `DatabaseMetaData.getTables` is for; in database systems that have the SQL standard information schema, that is probably the same table that gets queried, because `DatabaseMetaData.getTables` is modelled on the information schema.

Comment: @GurV, thanks I used the following, and got it to work. select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo';

Comment: This is only valid for SQL Server. As soon as your application needs to run on another DB, it wouldn't work. I suggest using the DB-independent way with JDBCs DataBaseMetaData.

Answer (score 2):

From [the Java API Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]))

```
ResultSet getTables(String catalog,
              String schemaPattern,
              String tableNamePattern,
              String[] types) throws SQLException
```

Since you only need results from a database, try to provide 'schemaPattern', like this:

```
ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, 'your-database', "%", types);
```

And you get what you want, no more no less.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Java, ut you can definitely use SQL fro that.

```
USE your_DB
GO
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%ticker%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

OR

```
select * from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_DB'
order by table_name,ordinal_position
```

Comment: That is specific to MS SQL Server when OP is about JDBC

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();
            String[] types = {"TABLE"};
            ResultSet RS = md.getTables(null, null, "%", types);
            while (RS.next()) {
                String table = RS.getString("TABLE_NAME");
                if (!table.equals("trace_xe_action_map")
                && !table.equals("trace_xe_event_map"))
                System.out.println(table);
            }
```